# htaccess subdomain redirect folder

Tags: php, .htaccess

Here's what I'm trying to do.

When you type admin.example.com I want users to be redirected to example.com/admin/ but I would like the url in the address bar to remain admin.example.com if possible.

I searched some solution for that but not working :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/admin%{REQUEST_URI} [L,P]
```

This also not work ... Is there any other setting in domain control panel ?

Comment: change the host to admin.example.com

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin\.example\.com                    
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/admin/$1 [L]`

Answer (score 0):

Just enable mod_proxy in apache and then in the virtual host enter the following and restart apache.

ProxyPass / http://example.com/admin/
 ProxyPassReverse / http://example.com/admin/

Comment: I did same but not work .. It give error Server not found.
Is there need to create subdomain ?